# Creating a new column derived from existing in the data source in tableau

Tags: python, if-statement, tableau-api, contains, tableau-desktop

I'm new to tableau and trying to create a new column based on an existing one in the tableau data source. This is a small chunk of the data.

**Flow**

Recycle/item1

Trash/item2

Organics/item3

Garbage/item4

I need to create a new column based on the flow column like below omitting the items data:

**Flow2**

Recycle

Trash

Organics

Garbage

I really need to create BAN's in tableau displaying the percentage of items flow from various buckets.

I'm trying to use the if-elseif-else and contains statements. But there's some sort of error displaying in the tableau. Can anyone pls help me on this and any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right Click your field Flow, select Transform-Split.

Then enter / as separator and click OK.

[image]

You will have a new calculated field like the one you asked for.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Fabio. It was very quick and helpful :)

Comment: Nice to know :-) If your need has been solved, please accept the answer (you can find a V sign next to the counter) in order to mark the thread as closed.